# Setting the namespace during a parse

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml, xml-namespaces

Hi I am currently having a problem with parsing an Xml string without any namespace, and added to an existing XElement with a namespace.

my code:

```
XElement elem = root.Element(xs + "methodCall");
if (elem != null)
{
    XElement e = XElement.Parse(this.MethodCallXML);

    elem.Add(e);
}
```

the result:

```
<methodCall>
  <methodCall service="activity" method="activityDeleteComment" xmlns="">
    <espSessionState>espSessionState1</espSessionState>
    <traceFlowCode>true</traceFlowCode>
    <params>
      <commentID>http://uri1</commentID>
      <isPermanentDelete>false</isPermanentDelete>
    </params>
  </methodCall>
</methodCall>
```

my problem is the  xmlns="" I cannot figure out how to create the node using a parse method and give it a default namespace to use.

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok I figured out how to add the namespace to the new XElement and all descendants

```
foreach (XElement ce in e.DescendantsAndSelf())
     ce.Name = xs + ce.Name.LocalName;
```

So far this solves my problem but if anyone can see a potential flaw or an easier way of doing this please let me know.